# Change String GMT Date Format into DQL Server UTCDate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a String.

> Mon Nov 16 07:36:05 IST 2015

I want to convert this String into SQl Server 2008 GETUTCDATE() Format.

> 2015-11-16 09:21:03.107

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible. MS SQL Server converts to datetime many formats. You can try this:

```
declare @d varchar(50)='Mon Nov 16 07:36:05 IST 2015'
;with dd as (--reorganize the string and build xml
select cast('<dd><d>'+replace(@d,' ','</d><d>')+'</d></dd>' as xml) d
)
select dateadd(hh,--add hours
case t.v.value('d[5]','varchar(10)') --process time zone
     when 'IST' then 2 --probably you need some reference table
     when 'EST' then -5 
     else 0 end,
cast(t.v.value('d[2]','varchar(10)') +' '+t.v.value('d[3]','varchar(10)') 
+' '+t.v.value('d[6]','varchar(10)') +' '+t.v.value('d[4]','varchar(10)') 
--Nov 16 2015 07:36:05 can be converted
    as datetime)) [date and time]
from dd cross apply dd.d.nodes('dd') t(v)
```